# Multiple variables in geom_bar or geom_col

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
Site TreesSDI InvertebratesSDI PlantsSDI BirdsSDI
1     1.31      2.48           1.35      1.84
2     1.46      2.80           1.61      2.05
3     1.78      2.50           2.29      2.40
```

I have this data recording Shannon's Diversity Index over three sites for trees, inverts, plants and birds. I have tried to get them on the same plot doing this but nothing is working.

```
ggplot(data) + 
  geom_bar(aes(x= data$Site, y=data$TreesSDI), stat= "identity" , position="dodge") + 
  geom_bar(aes(x= data$Site, y=data$InvertebratesSDI), stat= "identity" , position="dodge") + 
  geom_bar(aes(x= data$Site, y=data$PlantsSDI), stat= "identity" , position="dodge") + 
  geom_bar(aes(x= data$Site, y=data$BirdsSDI), stat= "identity" , position="dodge") +
  ggtitle("Shannon's Diversity of Trees, Invertebrates, Plants and Birds for all Three Sites") + 
  xlab("") + 
  ylab("Shannon's Diversity Index")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are two ways to plot it, but first I want to encourage using long-form data structure that works much better with ggplot. Also, because ggplot (and tidyverse in general) is quite non-standard evaluation heavy, I would discourage using the `$`-subsetting method inside `aes()`. Here is how you could go from wide format do long format:

```
zz <- "Site TreesSDI InvertebratesSDI PlantsSDI BirdsSDI
1     1.31      2.48           1.35      1.84
2     1.46      2.80           1.61      2.05
3     1.78      2.50           2.29      2.40"
df <- read.table(text = zz, header = T)

df <- reshape2::melt(df, id.vars = "Site")
```

Then, we could either plot it like the following:

```
ggplot(df, aes(Site, value, fill = variable)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge")
```

[image]

Or the following:

```
ggplot(df, aes(variable, value, fill = as.factor(Site))) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge")
```

[image]

Which one you choose would depend on what information you want to transmit with the visualisation or what comparison you would like to make.

Comment: Thank you!! I am comparing the biodiversity within the sites therefore I am thinking the first graph will be a better visual.

Comment: Is there any way to change the colours of the bars?

Comment: Yes, with any of the `+ scale_fill_*` functions. For example `+ scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "green", "blue", "yellow"))`.